How do I fix status code 90 when opening a file in COBOL
I am experiencing an issue in my COBOL application.
My application produces an error when opening a file in COBOL.
The file that I am trying to open has a fixed block size and
I want to display the content, since I am testing my application.
This is the error:

There was an unsuccessful OPEN or CLOSE of file EINGABE in program -------- ath the relative location X'FFFFFFFFD0E14BB8'.  Neither FILE STATUS nor an ERROR declarative were specified. The status code was 90. From compile unit TQTEST01 at entry point TQTEST01 at statement 60 at compile unit
offset +000001F6 at entry offset +000001F6 at address 2F2001F6.

This is my COBOL code:
IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.                                
PROGRAM-ID.     TQTEST01                                
ENVIRONMENT DIVISION.                                   
INPUT-OUTPUT SECTION.                                   
FILE-CONTROL.                                           
    SELECT INPUT-DATEI ASSIGN TO EINGABE                
    ORGANIZATION IS LINE SEQUENTIAL.                    
                                                         
DATA DIVISION.                                          
FILE SECTION.                                           
FD INPUT-DATEI.                                         
01 EINGELESENE-ZEILE PIC X(40).                         
                                                           
WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.                                
                                                        
01 BOERSENTABLE.                                        
  05 B-KENNUNGEN OCCURS 71 TIMES INDEXED BY B-IDX.      
    15 B-CODE PIC X(6).                                 
                                                        
01 IDX PIC 9(2).                                        
01 BOERSENCODE PIC X(6).                                
01 FORMATIERTE-ZEILE.                     
  05 SELEKTION-VOR-BOERSENCODE PIC X(33). 
  05 EINGELESENER-BOERSENCODE PIC X(7).   
                                          
01 BESTEHENDE-DATEI-EOF.                  
  05 BD-DATEISTATUS PIC X.                
   88 BD-EOF VALUE 'J'.                   
                                          
COPY LIBCOB.                              
                                          
PROCEDURE DIVISION.                       
                                          
STEUERLOGIK SECTION.                      
    PERFORM F001-INITIALISIERUNG-SECTION. 
    PERFORM F002-ABGLEICH-SECTION.        
    PERFORM F003-DATEI-SCHLIESSEN-SECTION.
    GOBACK.                               
STEUERLOGIK-EX.                           
     EXIT.                                
                                          
F001-INITIALISIERUNG-SECTION. 
DISPLAY "A".                  
OPEN INPUT INPUT-DATEI.       
DISPLAY "B".                  
DISPLAY "C".                  
MOVE '.....' TO B-CODE (1).
     CONTINUE.            
F001-INITIALISIERUNG-EXIT.
     EXIT.                
F002-ABGLEICH-SECTION.                           
      ....                               
      CONTINUE.                                   
 F002-ABGLEICH-SECTION-EXIT.                      
      EXIT.                                       
                                                  
 F003-DATEI-SCHLIESSEN-SECTION.                   
      CLOSE INPUT-DATEI.                          
      CONTINUE.                                   
 F003-DATEI-SCHLIESSEN-EXIT.                      
      EXIT.                                       

Kind Regards
Implementing a file with a fixed block size, check the JCL if it was written correctly

So... What does your JCL look like? For the error see https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/cobol-zos/6.4?topic=operations-common-processing-facilities, 90 is a quite general errror...

Is there any IEC161 message in your job-output? Or any other IEC..-message that could give a hint what's going wrong?

If the file has a fixed block size, then it seems the ORGANIZATION should be SEQUENTIAL not LINE SEQUENTIAL.

Rick Smith's comment is the correct answer.

Try associate a File-status variable to INPUT-DATE, and test it after each action related to that file (OPEN, CLOSE, READ, ...)
   FILE-CONTROL.                                           
      SELECT INPUT-DATEI ASSIGN TO EINGABE                
      ORGANIZATION IS LINE SEQUENTIAL
      FILE STATUS IS WS-FS-INPUT-DATEI.
...
   WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.                                
                                                        
   01 WS-FS-INPUT-DATEI         PIC X(02).                                        
      88 INPUT-DATEI-OK         VALUE '00'.
      88 INPUT-DATEI-EOF        VALUE '10'.
...
   OPEN INPUT INPUT-DATEI
   IF NOT INPUT-DATEI-OK
      DISPLAY 'ERROR OPENING FILE FS=' WS-FS-INPUT-DATEI.
...

After that you can better understand what is going on.

because of the status and the declarative not coded, there is an error at the first statement not successful - which as we already know is the very first OPEN - I therefore fail to see how adding this code helps in solving the issue :-?
